# How to add custom 401 handler in redux toolkit api integrations?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Basequery file code

```
export const buoyApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const state = getState();
      const { accessToken } = state?.user?.data;

      // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
      if (accessToken) {
        headers.set("Authorization", accessToken);
      }

      return headers;
    },
  }), // Replace with your API base URL
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

In other files, I am adding component wise apis and injecting to base one like below

```
import { buoyApi } from ".";

export const authApi = buoyApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchUser: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/users",
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginUserMutation } = authApi;
```

There are other APIs that I will integrate and want to redirect to the login page if any API response status is 401.

How to do this in a common place unlike handling this in all components? I don't want to add this logic in each component for all APIs.

I appreciate any help you can provide.